# Entity Framework 5 vs Telerik OpenAccess ORM (specifically)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, telerik-open-access

I am starting a new project and want advice on choosing an ORM. I know this topic has been brought up before, but this topic is specific to either Entity Framework 5 (not 4) or Telerik OpenAccess ORM.

The project will reside on Windows Azure and use Windows Azure SQL Database. I will migrate it to .NET 4.5 once 4.5 is live on Azure.

I am currently a Telerik Ultimate Collection subscriber.

Does anyone in the know have any pros/cons for this scenario? I am slightly leaning towards Telerik OpenAccess at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: I also have been wondering about this. But I found OpenAccess more mature and robust especially with databases other than SQL Server. 

A couple of features that really stood out for me are:

1) Easy-er database migration
2) Low-level ADO.NET API
3) Entity Designer and other VS tools
4) Support for multiple database
5) Its now FREE!

Unlike other commercial ORMs OpenAccess isn't too tied up to their controls.

I've successfully used EF, OpenAccess, XPO, and other lightweight ORMs like ORMLite and Dapper. It comes down to technical preference but I'm really loving OpenAccess so far.

Comment: This is not really and answer - but you may want to keep your eye on the following if you intend to use OpenAccess against Azure: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/orm/orm-express/backend-configuration-to-azure.aspx

Comment: Also, the following link may be useful: [7 Reasons to Choose OpenAccess ORM over Entity Framework](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm/getting-started/openaccess-vs-entity-framework.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, the comment:

"This is not really an answer - but you may want to keep your eye on the following if you intend to use OpenAccess against Azure: telerik.com/community/forums/orm/orm-express/… " does not reflect the correct product.

Deals with the FREE version of OpenAccess. Jayantha specified in his question that he is a "Ultimate Collection Subscriber".

The OpenAccess ORM is now compatible with Azure.

Some reasons to choose OpenAccess ORM over Entity Framework 5:

- Batch operations in Visual Designer
- Code generation for WCF Services
- Code generation for ASP.Net Web API Services
- Dynamic Model Modifications
- Custom Types Framework
- Built-in Validation Frameworks
- .NET 3.5 Support
- Pessimistic Concurrency
- Built-In L2 Cache
- Advanced Connection Pooling
- Pure XML mapping

What you lose when using OpenAccess that EF5 provides:

- Self-Tracking Entities
- Full support for Enumerations in Visual Designer (Partial support only)

Go figure!

Comment: Don't forget the included OpenAccess Profiler ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, both versions of OpenAccess are the same now, regardless of whether you're an Ultimate Collection subscriber or if you download the free version. See: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/orm/orm-express/openaccess-orm-free-edition-where-to-download.aspx#2326244

Comment: With entity Framework you can manage pessimistic concurrency, and what do you mean with Advance Connection Polling?

Comment: You can read about Telerik/OA connection pooling options here: http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/openaccess-tasks-model-tools-use-connection-pool.html